# How to make a pagination with dropdown selection?

Tags: php, pagination, options, dropdown, select

This is the code for the dropdown pagination. It uses a js controller too, but it works fine, so, I’m not adding it.

```
$total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
// only bother with the rest if we have more than 1 page!
if ( $total > 1 )  {
    // get the current page
    if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') ){
      $current_page = 1;
    }   
    // structure of "format" depends on whether we're using pretty permalinks
    $format = 'page/%#%/';
    $linkarray = paginate_links(array(
      'base' => str_replace( 'page/9999999/', '%_%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 9999999 ) ) ),
      'format' => $format,
      'current' => 0,
      'show_all' => true,
      'total' => $total,
      'mid_size' => 4,
      'prev_next' => False,
      'type' => 'array'
    ));
 
    $urlarray = array();
 
    foreach($linkarray as $value){
        $pieces = explode(' ',$value);
        foreach($pieces as $piece){
            if (substr(strtolower($piece),0,4) == 'http'){
                $urlarray[] = $piece;
            }
        }
    }
 
    echo '<div style="text-align: center">(Or jump to page ';
    echo '<select id="paginationpageselectcontrol" name="paginationpageselectcontrol">' . "n";
    $pagecounter = 1;
    foreach($urlarray as $url){
        echo '<option value="' .  $url . '"' . (($pagecounter == $current_page)?' selected':'') . '>' . $pagecounter . '</option>' . "n";
        $pagecounter = $pagecounter + 1;
    }
    echo '</select>' . "n";
    echo ' of ' . $total . ')</div>';
}
```

I think the error is around here:

```
    $urlarray = array();
 
    foreach($linkarray as $value){
        $pieces = explode(' ',$value);
        foreach($pieces as $piece){
            if (substr(strtolower($piece),0,4) == 'http'){
                $urlarray[] = $piece;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What’s the issue you’re having?  You don’t mention in your question.

Comment: That it is not working. It doesn’t show the pages just a black select option.

Comment: You're not really providing any indication as to what's going wrong.  Are there error messages, what does the console say, does the output HTML look like with your current method, etc.  What do the var_dumps for `$url_array` & `$link_array` look like?